# How to stop proceeding the request further with Micronaut filter

Tags: java, http, filter, micronaut

I'd like to use filter to validate the request.
Looking for a way to response with 403 if it's not valid.

```
@Filter("/hello")
public class HelloWorldFilter implements HttpServerFilter {
    @Override
    public Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> request, ServerFilterChain chain) {
        if(HelloWorldValidator.valid(request){
//if valid, keep proceeding further
           return chain.proceed(request);
        }else{
//if not valid, I want to stop here and return the 400 response
        ...
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by returning a response directly created in the filter.

```java
@Filter("/hello")
public class HelloWorldFilter implements HttpServerFilter {
    @Override
    public Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> request, ServerFilterChain chain) {

        if(HelloWorldValidator.valid(request){
           //if valid, keep proceeding further
           return chain.proceed(request);
        }
        else {
           // if not valid, I want to stop here and return the 403 response
           return Mono.just(HttpResponse.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN));
        }
    }
}
```